# Can I use wxWidgets for a close source commercial application?

Tags: licensing

wxWidgets is licensed under a modified LGPL License. This means I can sell it. But the original LGPL License forces me to release the source code. This is mentioned in the custom license in the library's page, but I haven't quite understood it. I'm not taking any risks, so **can I use it for a close source commercial application?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. The LGPL aspects of the licence protect the library itself, i.e. you can't sell a modified version of the library without providing your changes under the original licence. It does not however affect the applications linking with the library.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood it right, Wxwidgets is licensed under LGPL and has an *exception* you can make use of if you like. So this is LGPL + X, not exactly modifying the LGPL license (which would not be possible).

In [their own words](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/preamble.txt):

> Most files are distributed under the GNU Library General Public
>     License, version 2, with the special exception that you may create and
>     distribute object code versions built from the source code or modified
>     versions of it (even if these modified versions include code under a
>     different licence), and distribute such binaries under your own
>     terms.

I think this reflects pretty much what you're intended to do.

Also, like @VZ already answered, the LGPL does not stretch the copyleft over to your work, only for the library.

Additional, by making use of the terms in the exception to LGPL given by Wxwidgets, you can (but must not) pass on binaries that contain Wxwidget in binary (object-code) form with your own terms.

See as well the [Licence section on the Wxwidgets homepage](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm).